# When will AdoptOpenJDK 11 come for Apple with M1 chip?

Tags: java, javafx-11, adoptopenjdk, apple-m1, azul-zulu

I am using a [MacBook Air with the M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air#Third_generation_(Retina_with_Apple_silicon)) chip.

I tried Zulu JDK for M1 for development, and it works, however it does not work with OpenJFX. I have narrowed down the problem using Zulu vs AdoptOpenJDK.

Does anyone have any idea when OpenJDK will be compatible with the M1 chip?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Java 17, shipped 2021-09

There is an official sub-project on the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project for porting to the Apple Silicon hardware, [*JEP 391: macOS/AArch64 Port*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/391).

That work is done, built for Java 17, delivered in September of 2021.

The Apple Silicon port benefits from work done on the [Windows on ARM port](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/388). That work is done, delivered in [Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_16). Previous to that, [Linux on ARM](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/237) support was added to [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9).

So [Java 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17) for [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) on [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) ([AArch64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AArch64), [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)) Macs is **available now**.

Update: [Java 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_18) is now available too, as is early access [Java 19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_19).

You can choose from a variety of vendors to obtain an installer/binary. Off the top of my head, those may include Azul Systems, SAP, BellSoft, Amazon, Microsoft, [Adoptium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoptium) (formerly AdoptOpenJDK), Oracle, Red Hat/IBM, Pivotal, and perhaps more.

Regarding [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), at least two of those vendors, Azul Systems and BellSoft, offer an edition of their JDK product that bundles the [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) libraries. That may be of interest to you, as an alternative to adding the libraries to your app.

If you need further assistance with that [Azul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems) product, you can purchase support from that company. Or post a Question here with the detailed specifics of your JavaFX work and its point of failure on Apple Silicon. Ideally, provide a minimal example of code demonstrating the problem.

## Earlier Java

Some of those vendors listed above have back-ported earlier versions of Java (Java 8, Java 11, maybe others) to macOS on Apple Silicon. That work is *not* an official part of the OpenJDK project support for Apple Silicon, only Java 17+ is.

Comment: Thanks, this was very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Adoptium recently (2022-Oct-22) released Java 11 that supports Apple Silicon:

https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11

And for a summary of supported platforms:

https://adoptium.net/supported-platforms/